# How to fetch data for Optional List of custom data type in cassandra using Websudos Phanthom

Tags: scala, cassandra, dsl, phantom-dsl

I've a table in which one column is of type Option List of custom object.
How to fetch data from cassandra for this column using Websudos phantom.

Table Schema:

Server{
   hostName : String
   port: Int
   filter : Option[List[Filter]]
   }

Filter{
      filterKey : String,
      value : List(String)
   }

I've created a case class for both table "Server" and "Filter".

```
class Servers extends CassandraTable[Servers, Server] {
override lazy val tableName = "Servers"
object ipAddress extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]
object port extends IntColumn(this)
object filter extends JsonListColumn[Servers, server, Filter](this) {

def fromJson(str:String): Filter{
}

def toJson(obj: Filter){
}
```

This will provide List[filter], how to further convert into Option[List[Filter]]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would ever need to transform something to an `Option[List[Filter]]`, but let's assume you need a strong distinction between having no filters and having a filter list where all records where removed or something like that.

You implement the JSON methods for `List[Filter]`, and then in your `fromRow` method:

```
filters match {
   case list@(head :: tail) => Server(host, Some(list))
   case _ => Server(host, None)
}
```

You don't actually need to do this, an empty collection Cassandra will automatically be parsed to a `List.empty` or a `Nil`.

**Update**

If you really must use `Option[List[Filter]]` for reasons outside of my understanding:

```
class Servers extends CassandraTable[Servers, Server] {
  object ipAddress extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]
  object port extends IntColumn(this)
  object filter extends JsonListColumn[Servers, Server, Filter](this) {

    def fromJson(str: String): Filter = {
     JsonParser.parse(str).extract[Filter] // replace appropriately
    }

    def toJson(obj: Filter): String = {
      compactRender(Extraction.decompose(obj))
    }
  }

  def fromRow(row: Row): Server = {
    Server(
      ipAddress(row),
      port(row),
      filters(row) match {
        case list@(head :: tail) => Some(list)
        case _ => None
      }
    )
  }
```

}

Comment: My server case class looks like:

Server(
host: String,
port: String,
filters: option[List[Filter]]
)

So i want option[List[filter]] in Server after implementing JSON, not like Some or None.

JSON would be something like than return option[List] , but JSONListCoulmn used for  List[T]

do you some idea how to do that

Comment: @kin No, and I think you are choosing the wrong approach, having 2 monads is usually a smell unless the first level is `Future`. I don't think it's useful to have 2 types.